# OOME: Java heap space - any other options?

Tags: java, image-processing, garbage-collection

Im creating a Java application which can read input images and then creates an output image (combining the colours) and I have made it so that it reads TIFF files. The input images need to be multispectral satellite images, of which are typically quite large. Im converting to PNG by reading the TIFF files, saving them as PNG locally and then reading the saved PNG as a `BufferedImage`. The saved PNGs are about half the size (about 35MB).
I dont really want to extend the heap size if possible, would be nice if I could find a way to reallocate the memory, that would look really good if I can find a way to do it. But I guess using large image files means that its kind of inevitable, especially when I need to use `BufferedImages` and will potentially need to use more.

The code im using can be seen below, this is repeated 3 times, so 3 TIFF files are being read, saved and then read when a PNG. Essentially I never need the TIFF files after theyve been read  but at no point again so that will be a large amount of memory used, is there a way to recycle that memory?

---

```
private void importBlueActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    int img3 = blueFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(img3==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
        try {
            File file3 = blueFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            BufferedImage bi3 = ImageIO.read(file3);
            ImageIO.write(bi3, "PNG", new File("img3_tmp.png"));
            image3 = ImageIO.read(new File("img3_tmp.png"));
            //image3 = new BufferedImage(img3_tmp.getWidth(), img3_tmp.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            ImageIcon imageIcon3 = new ImageIcon(image3);
            Image blueInput = imageIcon3.getImage().getScaledInstance(300, 300, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            imageIcon3.setImage(blueInput);
            blueLabel.setIcon(imageIcon3);
            System.out.println(file3+"\n"+image3);
            inputCounter++;
            checkInput();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: When you say you've "made it so that it reads TIFF files", does that mean you implemented a custom ImageReader?  If so, is it possible that the reader isn't cleaning up some resource?

Comment: No im using a `BufferedImage` for the TIFF file, using JAI which can is done in these lines:
`BufferedImage bi3 = ImageIO.read(file3);
ImageIO.write(bi3, "PNG", new File("img3_tmp.png"));`

Comment: Are you actually seeing OutOfMemoryErrors, or just concerned about the potential for them?  As long as the original BufferedImage isn't being referenced anywhere else, it should be marked for GC and collected if/when the VM needs memory.  If you're seeing OOMEs, then it's possible the data you're actively using (i.e. your 3 "smaller" files and whatever objects are used in combining them, which I don't think you show here) is too large for your heap settings.  Have you done any memory profiling to see how your heap is actually being used?

Comment: I am seeing the errors when I try to load in the final image, I just ran the memory profiler and the max heap size used is 195mb or 235mb which doesnt seem to make much sense to me. It does spike, im assuming when it loads the PNG back in, which would put it over 235mb.

Comment: Can you try temporarily increasing the heap size (say, doubling it) for testing purposes?  It might be interesting to know how high it would spike if it weren't running out entirely - i.e. does it just need a little more breathing room, or is it really running away?

Comment: I doubled it but this was only sufficient to read in the 3 images, to actually run the algorithm I needed to triple it although it says it only actually needed 550mb. I dont actually mind increasing the memory allocation but my head is telling I dont actually need to, as technically the only significant things in the heap will be the loaded PNG and the TIFFs should have been collected but GC doesnt seem to be doing a great deal.

Comment: Since the heap is divided into multiple generations, perhaps you're running out of space in one generation (which might explain why you get OOMEs despite not reaching the "max" heap size).  I personally haven't ever done anything with fine-tuning the generation sizes, but it might be worth looking into: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abeik/index.html

Comment: Why do you read the PNG back after writing it? Do you expect it to differ from the TIFF you read it from? I think `bi3 = null;` after `ImageIO.write` will save you from a couple of OOME situations, but remember that `BufferedImage`s are backed by a byte array, and need a *contiguous block of memory*.

Comment: Because the PNG is saved as an RGB images as opposed to 8-bit Grey TIFF which I cannot manipulate. If theres an easier way to do this please let me know :)

Comment: Not sure why you say you can't manipulate 8 bit gray TIFF, so it's hard to say what would be an easier way... Creating an RGB image and painting the grey TIFF onto it would work, but not save (much) memory. It is probably even possible to instruct ImageIO to read the 3 gray TIFFs into a single RGB image, without any temporary images if that's what you want. But it requires some knowledge of the ImageIO API. I suggest you ask a different question.